# html a:active doesnt work?

Tags: html, css

***CSS:***

```
// Highlight to show that the user is viewing current tab.    
// css for the active tab

.HeaderTabs li.tab a { 
   display: block;    //anchor tab 
   padding: 12px 8px 12px 8px;
}

.HeaderTabs li.tab a:link {
   outline: none;  //link works 
   text-decoration: none;
}

.HeaderTabs li.tab a:hover {  //this works hovering over the text
   color: #A4C639;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.HeaderTabs li.tab a:active { //this doesnt work 
   color: #A4C639;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Which browser you are testing as this doesn't work in IE..

Comment: @vascowhite: probably, "why doesn't this work"

Comment: How do i make the active work ? so that the user knows that they are  viewing the current page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:active` selector comes in action when the element is **active**, for example when you keep an element **clicked**, the styles will apply, if you want to style your current active tab you need to use jQuery or server side programming for that, you can't style your current active tab by just using `:active` selector

[**More Reference**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active)

Comment: or a CSS hack including use of radio buttons and their labels ;)

Comment: ok thanks for your answer.i have to look into java script now , Any suggesstions would be great ?

Comment: @Shashank Sorry, but I don't have much Idea for javascript as I use server side, you can google it out that how it works..

Comment: ok no worries, will google..Cheers

Comment: @Shashank: You don't need JS for this.

Comment: @jawad, Could you please tell me how do i do that ?

Comment: @Jawad LOL, how you'll apply that class?

Comment: @RandomGuy: LOL Indeed. it's very common mate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be confusing what 'active' means. ':active' in CSS refers to the state of the link when it's clicked (which can be a matter of milliseconds in some browsers). If you want to make the tab that refers to the current page look different, you'll need to add some kind of selector to it and style that differently.

Answer (score 1):

The active state is set on a link when the user is clicking on it. Once the user releases the click the link is no more active. If you change the color of the active link (different color than the hover state) you will see the difference.

You should add your own "selected" class to the link once the tab is effectively selected either using JavaScript or on server-side.

Comment: so i need to use java script to make it work, Thank you

Comment: If you use JavaScript to display the clicked tab, then yes use JavaScript to change the state of the selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think :active only works the moment you click on the link, when you mouseUp it's not "active" anymore.

If you want that tab to keep on a color, just define another class.

```
.activeTab {
color: #A4C639;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and throught javascript or jquery add that class to the tab.

Answer (score 1):

> This pseudo-class matches any element that’s in the process of being activated. It would apply, for instance, for the duration of a mouse-click on a link, from the point at which the mouse button’s pressed down until the point at which it’s released again. The pseudo-class does not signify a link to the active, or current, page—that’s a common misconception among CSS beginners.

[Read This](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-active)

```
 li class="current"

.HeaderTabs li.tab a.current {
color: #A4C639; 
font-weight: bold; 
 }
```

Additionaly comments in CSS are not done with `//`, thats Javascript. Use `/* Cooment */`

**EXAMPLE**

**HTML/MARKUP**

File = `index.html`

```
<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="index.html"</a>Home</li>
<li><a href="about_us.html"</a>About Us</li>
<li><a href="news.html"</a>News</li>
<li><a href="products.html"</a>Products</li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html"</a>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

File = `abouts_us.html`

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"</a>Home</li>
<li class="current"><a href="about_us.html"</a>About Us</li>
<li><a href="news.html"</a>News</li>
<li><a href="products.html"</a>Products</li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html"</a>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

File = `news.html`

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"</a>Home</li>
<li><a href="about_us.html"</a>About Us</li>
<li class="current"><a href="news.html"</a>News</li>
<li><a href="products.html"</a>Products</li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html"</a>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

File = `products.html`

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"</a>Home</li>
<li><a href="about_us.html"</a>About Us</li>
<li><a href="news.html"</a>News</li>
<li class="current"><a href="products.html"</a>Products</li>
<li><a href="contact_us.html"</a>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

File = `contact_us.html`

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"</a>Home</li>
<li><a href="about_us.html"</a>About Us</li>
<li><a href="news.html"</a>News</li>
<li><a href="products.html"</a>Products</li>
<li class="current"><a href="contact_us.html"</a>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

**STYLES/CSS**

```
li.current
{
color: #A4C639; 
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Aditionally you may need to give the `class="current"` to the `<a>` instead of the `<li>` and use

```
a.current
{
color: #A4C639; 
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: that isn't working for me jawad

Comment: OK. See My edited answer and Example. And to @RandomGuy

Comment: @Shashank: What's not working for you?

Comment: <div class="HeaderTabs">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="divide">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="<?= $hname; ?>index.php"><? $lang->text('HOME_OVERVIEW'); ?></a></li>
        <li class="divide">&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="<?= $hname; ?>page.php"><? $lang->text('HOME_PAGE'); ?></a></li>
        <li class="divide">&nbsp;</li> </ul></div>

Comment: this is the current php code i am using .

Comment: Just give the <a> a class of "current" as in <a class="current href="anything.html">anything</a> and use a.current {color: red; font-weight: bold;}. Your above code is different from your question code. Do you want to give the current tab (that the user in on) some styles using CSS?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17693/discussion-between-jawad-and-shashank)

Comment: yeah, i want to high-light the current tab that the user is on..

Comment: That is what the code does mate. As I explained, All you need to do is give the <a> a class of "current" in each file. For example if you have this file "index.php" and inside you have <a href="<?= $hname; ?>index.php"><? $lang->text('HOME_OVERVIEW'); ?></a>, than give the <a> class of "current" such as <a class="current" href="<?= $hname; ?>index.php"><? $lang->text('HOME_OVERVIEW'); ?></a> and use a.current {color: red; font-weight: bold;}